# Send friend request from IOS using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

i'm trying to send friend request from IOS using facebook SDK,

Here is my code

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My Title", @"title",
                                   @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                                   FrienduserId, @"id",
                                   nil];


    [FBWebDialogs  presentDialogModallyWithSession:appDelegate.session dialog:@"friends" parameters:[params mutableCopy] handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"done");
        }
    }];
```

its asking Confirm message (refer friendrequest.png), after click confirm button it shows error

[image]

"Sorry, something went wrong, we're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can" (refer error.png)

[image]

can any one help me please

Facebook SDK version 3.5.1 and xCode version 4.6

Comment: Try adding the parameter `show_error` with a value of true to your dialog parameters, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#common (I think it should work under iOS as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My Title", @"title",
                                   @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                                   FrienduserId, @"id",
                                   nil];    
[FBWebDialogs  presentDialogModallyWithSession:appDelegate.session dialog:@"friends" parameters:[params mutableCopy] handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"done");
            }
```

This should at least solve part of your problem. There may still be something else wrong, I just fixed your syntax.

Comment: hi, its give error near " if (error) { " as "use of undeclared identifier 'error'".

Comment: I don't know then. Take a screenshot and post a link to it

Comment: @SantaClaus: appdelegate.sessiion means what here

Comment: @Seeker not completely sure. It was used the in the question.